# TermRangeFilter Lucene

Tags: java, filter, lucene

I am trying to add a filter to a search and I keep getting following error: `The constructor TermRangeFilter(String, String, String, boolean, boolean) is undefined`

[The constructor is defined that way in Lucene documentation]

Has anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are looking at old documentation.  That constructor would be correct in Lucene version 3.6 and before, but [from 4.0 on](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeFilter.html#TermRangeFilter%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef,%20org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), you need to pass in a [`BytesRef`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/BytesRef.html) for your `upperTerm` and `lowerTerm` arguments.

Converting a `String` to a `BytesRef` is as easy as:

```
new BytesRef(string)
```